# Std class object to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

as am trying to stdClass Object array to normal array...product id and category separated by commas... how do i convert std class object to normal array...

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [product_id] => SHIRT61
    [product_category] => 4
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
    [product_id] => SHIRT51
    [product_category] => 5
  )
)
```

to `product_id = {'SHIRT61','SHIRT51'}` and `product_category = {'5','7'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does your model look like where this data is being generated?  If you query your database to retrieve arrays you won't have to worry about converting the data.

In codeigniter you can use `row_array()` instead of `row()` or `result_array()` instead of `result()`

For example change this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
$query->get->row();
return $query;
```

Into this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
$query->get->row_array();
return $query;
```

In this example I'm using `row()`/`row_array()`, but the same applies for `result()`/`result_array()`

Comment: thanks daniel....i have used result_array().... both $array = json_decode(json_encode($objArray), true); & result_array() are rite....

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($objArray), true);
```

This will work for recursive array also.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

Or

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

Comment: it returns the same std class object